# SQL Find Average Multiple Columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the average of multiple columns in my SQL database. This will be used to aggregate the average score of my student's attempts on various quizzes. This is the query I am using right now:

```
SELECT 
AVG((`2.R.1` + `2.R.2` + `2.R.3` + `3.R.1` + `3.R.2` + `3.R.5`)/6) as avg
FROM standards_data
WHERE `uuid` = 4
```

**Here is the table structure (part cut off because of length, but you get the idea):**
[image]

When I run this query, there are no errors, but it just returns a null value. Due to the nature of this database, there will be times when a column is set to NULL (as seen in the 2.R.2 example)

**Here is the outcome of the query:**
[image]

Is there a better way I need to go about doing this? I'm still learning SQL, so any table setup advice would also be appreciated.

Comment: When you add the SQL tag, you should also add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using (which is suggested in the SQL tag wiki), as functionality and syntax varies between them. Adding that DBMS tag not only gets your question to the people who can answer it more quickly, but also avoids wasting both your time and the time of people who try to help by posting an answer only to find out it won't work on the DBMS you're using. Please [edit] to add that DBMS specific tag. Thanks.

Comment: Also, the issue you're having is the columns with NULL. You can't average a NULL column, because NULL has no known value (that's why it's NULL). The way to deal with that issue depends on the DBMS you're using, which of course we don't know because you didn't add a tag for it.

Comment: Depending on your database management system, you'll want to coalesce NULL values to 0.

Comment: Seriously consider revising your schema. The rest is noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL, you can get the average -- ignoring `NULL`s -- using:

```
SELECT (COALESCE(`2.R.1`, 0) + COALESCE(`2.R.2`, 0) + COALESCE(`2.R.3`, 0) + COALESCE(`3.R.1`, 0) + COALESCE(`3.R.2`, 0) + COALESCE(`3.R.5`, 0)) /
       ((`2.R.1` IS NOT NULL) + (`2.R.2` IS NOT NULL) + (`2.R.3` IS NOT NULL) + (`3.R.1` IS NOT NULL) + (`3.R.2` IS NOT NULL) + (`3.R.5` IS NOT NULL)
       )
FROM standards_data
WHERE `uuid` = 4;
```

This calculates the average *within* each row.  If you actually want the average across rows as well, you can use `AVG()` with the above as the argument.

Answer (score 1):

`COALESCE()` is an ANSI SQL standard function that most databases now support. This function accepts multiple parameters and if any of those are NULL it reads the next parameter to the right. So, this is useful here as you can return zero instead of NULL and then your average calculation can proceed.

```
SELECT 
   AVG((
       COALESCE(`2.R.1`,0)
     + COALESCE(`2.R.2`,0) 
     + COALESCE(`2.R.3`,0) 
     + COALESCE(`3.R.1`,0) 
     + COALESCE(`3.R.2`,0) 
     + COALESCE(`3.R.5`,0))/6) as avg
FROM standards_data
WHERE `uuid` = 4
```

Notes:

1. Many databases have their own unique function to inspect for NULL and instead return something else. MySQL has `IFNULL` MS SQL Server has `ISNULL` and Oracle has `NVL` and this is why we ask you to specify which databases you actually use in the tags.
2. Despite the existence of database specific functions that are similar to `COALESCE` I strongly recommend you use this if your dbms supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you were using something like mysql, the below would work.

```
SELECT 
    AVG((COALESCE(`2.R.1`, 0) + COALESCE(`2.R.2`, 0) + COALESCE(`2.R.3`, 0) + COALESCE(`3.R.1`, 0) + COALESCE(`3.R.2`, 0) + COALESCE(`3.R.5`, 0))/6) as avg
FROM standards_data
WHERE `uuid` = 4
```